# Why can I find the i-th element of a list in constant time?

Tags: list, big-o

I'm going through an algorithm lecture and it is telling me that I can "look up the i-th element of a list in constant time".

Can someone explain why this is to me? Shouldn't the worst case scenario be linear time O(n) because what if the i-th element is outside of the list? Then it goes through all the elements of the list and realize it is not there hence O(size of the list:n)?

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: You need to provide more context. `List` can mean a lot of different data structures, and some of them (eg: linked lists) absolutely do not have constant access time.

Comment: @CollinD: oh my bad, I'm pretty new. This was an introduction to computer science lecture so we haven't gotten to Linked list in detail yet. I'm assuming he's talking about regular lists. I'm getting it from this lecture around the 2:50 mark: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjLbxB9TXJs

Comment: I have a suspicion that this professor is using the term `List` as a standin for `Array` (maybe the context is Python or some such language that shares that terminology). I'd just try looking back at the previous lectures for the details (since the one you linked is lecture 10)

Comment: @CollinD, ahh I see, thanks!! I would like to ask a follow up question if you don't mind - I noticed that Arrays are constant look up because of RAM (one of the answers I see on here mentions: "You can go to any location if you know its address without traversing all the memory before that location.") Can you give me some pointers on how this is done? Wouldn't they also do some sort of searching and matching to locate the right buckets on RAM, therefore won't be constant time?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can't achieve lookup in constant time for a classical linked list (as you have to traverse the nodes somehow).

But you *can* achieve constant time access with a contiguous array.